# How do I query Sitecore items by first version created date?

Tags: xpath, sitecore

It's quite easy to write an XPath or Sitecore Query/Fast query to get all items within a date range:

E.g.

```
/sitecore/content/*[@__created>='20130301T000000' and @__created<'20130427T000000']
```

However, this kind of query only looks at the latest version of an item, so it seems impossible to find the actual **item's** `created` date (not the **version's** `created` date).

I could write a bit of C# code to do the querying but that would involve first retrieving version 1 of *every single item in my database* before I could then do my filter on `created` date. This would be mind-bogglingly slow.

Is it possible to do with XPath/Query notation/Fast? If not, is there a way I can do it that will be quick?

Comment: Why do you need to get the date when the item (version 1) has been created (Might be there's some other way)? Are you certain that'll work on live environments? (As far as I know, the web database only has 1 version - the latest one)

Also, you can't count on retrieving version 1 entirely - it might've been deleted at some point. If you do find a solution for this, make sure you select the lowest version number.

Comment: @Trayek This will be for maintenance on our master database - it's not required for the live website. We have various scripts that run to help us maintain and analyse our content. Good call on the lowest version number instead of expecting version 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I thought of something that might work: 
Create a new field which all your items will get. Then in this field, on the creation of an item (not version), you enter the datetime in there. 
When versions get deleted, that's fine, because all versions will have that field, with the exact same value.

The only thing is, you'll have to run a script once to loop through your existing items to populate the field with the correct value for each item.

You can then use your XPath query same as now.

Comment: Thinking out of the box! +1

Comment: Well, inside the SO _Your Answer_ box at least :-p

Comment: @trayek Interesting idea, but like you say it would still require some kind of C# script to populate the data (the purpose is to search through historical items).

Comment: Yes, it would require some script - but the slow part of it would be only once (populating existing items), the rest you could handle in item:created event for instance. 

This way, you only have to get 1 version of the item (the current one) instead of getting the lowest version while you're running your script.